# (SwiftUI) How to make text hidden when view loads and become visible once toggle is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, toggle, userdefaults

I'm trying to create a view with a `toggle`. the toggle changes ui preferences. when the toggle is changed it changes the `Text` below. as it stands the easiest way to do this is

```
        VStack {
            Toggle("toggle me", isOn: $isOn)
            Text( isOn ? "I've been toggled once more" : "I've been toggled again" )
         }
```

what I would like is for the `Text( isOn ? "I've been toggled once more" : "I've been toggled again" )` to be hidden until *after* the toggle is interacted with. it doesn't matter if it's been toggled on or off, I would like to make the Text visible once the toggle has been interacted with. I've tried to use the `.onChange(of: perform: )` but `perform:`  requires a void method. so I can't put the Text in there. I have tried using a boolean/opacity fix as shown in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58276635/swiftui-setting-view-visibility-based-on-a-property-value) but same problem. can't change a Boolean value in perform. only void methods are allowed. I did try to use `onTapGesture` but that didn't work at all. I had a print statement in there that never once printed. not sure what else to do. is it possible to keep text hidden until the toggle has been interacted with? here's my code

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @State private var isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isOn")
    @State private var showText = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack { // vstack 0
            Text("Profile Page")
                .font(.title)
            
            Text("Are you ready to toggle?")
                .font(.title2)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            
            VStack { // vstack 1
                Toggle("toggle this", isOn: $isOn)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("toggled") // this never prints
                    }
//                    .onChange(of: isOn, perform: { value in
//                        value ? Text("yes") : Text("no")
//                        print("value = \(value)")
//                    })
// the Text here never shows up. and can't set showText = true here
                Text( isOn ? "Thank you." : "Toggled again" )
                    .opacity(showText ? 1 : 0)
// from the linked stackoverflow answer. trying to make this boolean work. is it a lost cause? 
            } // vstack 1
        } // vstack 0
        .frame(
            width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
            height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 200,
            alignment: .top)
    }
}
```

So is what I'm asking even possible? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate [Dynamically hiding view in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490250/dynamically-hiding-view-in-swiftui) - although I'd be interested in a version which could watch a state value

Comment: [How to Hide a SwiftUI View - Visible / Invisible / Gone](https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/how-to-hide-a-swiftui-view-visible-invisible-gone) might also be useful

Comment: @MadProgrammer I saw the first one and it got me to change from an if/else to a ternary operator for the Text. haven't seen the second one I'll look at it. but the first one seems more relevant for toggling visibility. I want the Text to load hidden then appear once the toggle has been tapped. toggle on or toggle off - the Text stays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can continue to use a `@State` variable for `showText`, which, according to your requirements, should only be shown once the `Toggle` is interacted with. Rather than using a `@State` variable that is initialized with a `UserDefaults` value, you probably want to use `@AppStorage` for `isOn`.

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("isOn") private var isOn : Bool = false //@AppStorage syncs this value with UserDefaults automatically
    @State private var showText = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack { // vstack 0
            Text("Profile Page")
                .font(.title)
            
            Text("Are you ready to toggle?")
                .font(.title2)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            
            VStack { // vstack 1
                Toggle("toggle this", isOn: $isOn)
                    .onChange(of: isOn, perform: { value in
                        showText = true //Once the toggle is interacted with, set showText to true
                    })
                if showText { //only show the text if showText == true
                    Text( isOn ? "Thank you." : "Toggled again" )
                }
            } // vstack 1
        } // vstack 0
        .padding(.bottom, 200) //try not to use UIScreen dimensions in SwiftUI -- default to using padding instead when possible
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what I needed

Comment: Yes, this is nice because using `.opacity` will leave a space for the "hidden" text, whereas this will add/remove the view from the view hierarchy depending on `showText`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different take on how to solve this. You can have `@AppStorage` store an optional value, so long as you extend optionals to
conform to `RawRepresentable`. This allows you to eliminate the `showText` state variable, and allows you a definite state with 3 possibilities, true, false and nil. Since you don't want the text to show up until the `Toggle` has been toggled once, the nil state allows you to know this. Once `Toggle` has been toggled, `isOn` will have either a true or false value from that point forward, unless you set it somewhere else to nil again.

There is one complexity that this adds. `Toggle` does not take an Bool?. Therefore, you have to write your own binding for it so that there is a definite value being passed in to the `Toggle`.

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("isOn") private(set) var isOn: Bool? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack { // vstack 0
            Text("Profile Page")
                .font(.title)
            
            Text("Are you ready to toggle?")
                .font(.title2)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            
            VStack { // vstack 1
                Toggle("toggle this", isOn: Binding<Bool>(
                    get: { isOn ?? false },
                    set: { isOn = $0 }
                ))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("toggled") // this never prints
                    }
                Text( isOn == true ? "Thank you." : "Toggled again" )
                    // Compare isOn to nil, instead of use showText
                    .opacity(isOn != nil ? 1 : 0)
            } // vstack 1
            Spacer()
        } // vstack 0
        .padding()
    }
}

// This extension allows Optionals to be written to @AppStorage
extension Optional: RawRepresentable where Wrapped: Codable {
    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "{}"
        }
        return json
    }

    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
              let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = value
    }
}
```